# What is the difference between the summation in np.einsum and np.sum?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why is `np.einsum` more precise in its reduce operation than `np.sum`? The multiplication produces the same values, it seems during the `np.sum` call precision is lost compared to `np.einsum`. I see that `np.sum` is just `np.add` reduced over the array and `np.add` is just pairwise summation. How does `np.einsum`'s summation differ?

```py
test_data = np.random.random((100, 90, 180)).astype(np.float32)
test_weights = np.random.random((90, 180)).astype(np.float32)

test1 = np.einsum('...abc,...bc->...a', test_data, test_weights)
test2 = np.sum(np.einsum('...abc,...bc->...abc', test_data, test_weights), axis=(1, 2))
print(np.array_equal(test1, test2)) 
# False
test3 = np.sum(np.multiply(test_data, test_weights), axis=(1, 2))
print(np.array_equal(test1, test3)) 
# False
print(np.array_equal(test2, test3)) 
# True

print(np.array_equal(np.einsum('...abc,...bc->abc', test_data, test_weights), np.multiply(test_data, test_weights)))
# True
```

Comment: Sounds like luck

Answer (score 1):

The pure `einsum` matches this `sum`:

```
In [5]: test4 = (test_data * test_weights).sum(axis=(1,2))
In [6]: test4.shape
Out[6]: (100,)
In [7]: np.allclose(test1,test4)
Out[7]: True
```

For that matter, the other `test` match, using `allclose`:

```
In [8]: np.allclose(test1,test2)
Out[8]: True
In [9]: np.allclose(test1,test3)
Out[9]: True
```

Floats should be compared with `allclose`, since they are rarely close enough to match with `equal`.

I don't know why you consider the `einsum` to be more "exact".

Something else to add to your tests

```
test5 = (test_data.reshape(100,-1)@test_weights.ravel())
test6 = np.einsum('...abc,...bc->...a', test_data, test_weights, optimize=True)
```

Comment: I used more "precise" as `np.einsum` produce a few more decimal places. I was getting a absolute mean difference between `test1` and `test2` of 1.7089844e-5, I'm guessing this is small enough to write off as round-off error for float32?

Comment: As long as the dtype is the same, the number of displayed decimal places dosen't matter.  You have random numbers, and a (100,) shape result.